# Google Maps API - Geolocation not working in Firefox

Tags: google-maps, firefox, geolocation

Recently I noticed that geolocation doesn't work on Firefox when using Google Maps API. After googleing for a while, I tried showing my current location (from a laptop, not from mobile) on Google Maps, but it didn't work there as well.

Here's what I have in my `geo.wifi.uri` in the `about:config` Firefox's tab:

`https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=%GOOGLE_API_KEY%`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What do you send in request body? Can you post your JSON object?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/tntpjd/location_access_not_working/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button might be of use.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem, and from what I found, we can't use Google's Geolocation unless we get our own API key. If you don't mind, you can use Mozilla's Geolocation, but the results will be different from Google's.

You can change `https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=%GOOGLE_API_KEY%` to `https://location.services.mozilla.com/v1/geolocate?key=%MOZILLA_API_KEY%`

[Source](http://www.ghacks.net/2015/03/04/mozilla-location-services-to-replace-googles-geolocation-service-in-firefox/)